# vectorized indexing of matrices with other matrices (in octave)

Tags: matrix, indexing, octave, vectorization

Suppose we have a 2D (5x5) matrix:

```
test =  

39   13   90    5   71  
60   78   38    4   11  
87   92   46   45   35  
40   96   61   17    1  
90   50   46   89   63
```

And a second 2D (5x2) matrix:

```
tidx =

1   3  
2   4  
2   3  
2   4  
4   5
```

And now we want to use tidx as an idex into test, so that we get the following output:

```
out =

39   90  
78    4  
92   46      
96   17  
89   63
```

One way to do this is with a for loop...

```
for i=1:size(test,1)     
   out(i,:) = test(i,tidx(i,:)); 
end
```

### Question:

Is there a way to vectorize this so the same output is generated without a for loop?

Comment: Unless your problem has a specific need for a square (i.e. 5x5) matrix, it's a good idea to use a matrix that is not a perfect square for testing and asking questions. This ensures that you don't mix up dimensions by swapping rows(test) and columns(test) by accident. It wouldn't show up when testing a square matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
test(repmat([1:rows(test)]',1,columns(tidx)) + (tidx-1)*rows(test))
```

What you describe is an index problem. When you place a matrix all in one dimension, you get

```
test(:) =
39
60
87
40
90
13
78
92
96
50
90
38
46
61
46
 5
 4
45
17
89
71
11
35
 1
63
```

This can be indexed using a single number. Here is how you figure out how to transform tidx into the correct format.

First, I use the above reference to figure out the index numbers which are:

```
outinx =
 1 11
 7 17
 8 13
 9 19
20 25
```

Then I start trying to figure out the pattern. This calculation gives a clue:

```
(tidx-1)*rows(test) =
0   10
5   15
5   10
5   15
15   20
```

This will move the index count to the correct column of test. Now I just need the correct row.

```
outinx-(tidx-1)*rows(test) =
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
```

This pattern is created by the for loop. I created that matrix with:

```
[1:rows(test)]' * ones(1,columns(tidx))
```

*EDIT: This does the same thing with a built in function.

```
repmat([1:rows(test)]',1,columns(tidx))
```

I then add the 2 together and use them as the index for test.

Comment: CharityAbbott - Thank you very much!